# Jenkins taking different time to build the same file

Tags: ant, build, continuous-integration, jenkins

I have started to use jenkins to build my project. I build my project yesterday and it took me  26 sec to build my flex sdk. I build the same file today and it took me 19 min to build the same file. Could anyone explain how this is happening ? I am trying to optimize my build scripts and I am not able to understand if there is something wrong with my build file or with jenkins.

**This is the build that took 19 min**[image: This is the build that took 19 min]

**This is the build that took 26 sec** [image]

**This is my second build running after the first one and the part of MXMLC Compiles took around 27 min out of the total 34 min**
[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this happening consistently? Was your system perhaps overloaded when the second build occurred? e.g. A backup running or some CPU-intensive process?

If you install the [Timestamper](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Timestamper) plugin for Jenkins, you will be able to see which parts are taking longer.

Comment: I noticed that the build time varies a lot like 2 min when I first build this, then it went down and today it was very unusual. No there was no backup or any CPU intensive process happening during the build.  The part were unzipping the Flex-SDK took nearly 8 min but unzipping the YUI-compressor took 3 min.

Comment: The new screenshot you added shows a different job, so I guess we can't compare that to the previous ones. Are you running only a Jenkins master server, or do you have additional build slaves? Where are these jobs running?

Comment: But overall it sounds potentially like you have way too little disk space and/or RAM and some intense swapping is going on, which would explain why unzipping a small ZIP file takes 3 minutes. In which case, that's not a Jenkins problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is your Jenkins system on a box all by itself? Is this on Windows?

On Windows systems, files can become locked for all sorts of reasons. I've had problems just because I had a Windows Explore window open up to a directory where Jenkins wanted to overlay a file. Jenkins froze up until I closed my Explorer window. Could this be an issue?

Where is the task being delayed? Install the Jenkins timestamper plugin, and that'll show you what tasks are taking so long. From there, you can narrow down your investigation a bit.